# Check In Document using Adobe Reader Returns Error Message

Tags: 2010, document-library, error, pdf, check-in

There is an error message that is being returned when a pdf document is being checked in using Adobe Reader XI.

This is being reported by some users.

All users have the same permission level for the site and the document library, Approver.

All users environment: IE9, Adobe Reader XI, Windows 7.

Steps to check out / check in document:

1. Click on document on SharePoint 2010 Document Library
2. Dialog box click 'Check Out and Open'
3. Add a comment/highlight
4. Check In Document: File->SharePoint Server-> Check In
5. Add a comment to the check in dialog box
6. After clicking okay the following error message appears

> Adobe Reader cannot check in the document as it has been deleted or there is a network connection problem. Please check your network connection or contact the server administrator.

[image: Adobe Reader Check In Document Error Message]

I created a new document library to test if the document check in would work on another library. And it did work on the new library, the permission levels are the same, they are inherited from the site itself.

One difference I did note was that the document library with the issue does have over 5000 items, which is the list view threshold.

How can this issue be resolved?